# Application logging for Read permission users

Tags: sql-server, delphi

Authorized users have read/view access to all production data accessed through the application and all of its components due to the application’s design. None of this read activity is logged.

Therefore, people with access to application can access all information within the system and are not restricted to just clients/specific component that apply to them.

**How to maintain the Read logging in the system?**
Application includes Delphi fro Frond end design, MS sql server for back end.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Delphi. Auditing user access is something known by the *database*. This is a database-related question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to maintain the Read logging in the system?

What you are looking for is called Audit.. you can configure it like below.Take below screens as guidance and modify as per your needs..

Further you can also use Audit as described here:[Auditing SELECT statements in SQL Server 2008](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sreekarm/2009/01/05/auditing-select-statements-in-sql-server-2008/)

I would go with extended events as it is light weight

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Who downvoted one of the few solutions that would work reliably in production without harming performane?

Comment: PS: SQL Audit uses Extended Events itself and quite fast. Manually configured XEs can be faster only if they are carefully configured to capture less data and persist it in a faster way

Comment: If we follow this approach we may have a problem like it can slows down the performance.Do we have any alternative apart from this...?

Comment: No,Auditing always has some cost.

Comment: I don't see any new changes in 2016